# Open URL in same window and in same tab

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, href

I want to open a link in the same window and in the same tab that contains the page with the link.

When I try to open a link by using `window.open`, then it opens in new tab—not in the same tab in the same window.

Comment: You might want to check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470097/difference-between-self-top-and-parent-in-the-anchor-tag-target-attribute) to understand differences between the proposed methods below, like `_self` and `_top` which "look-alike".

Answer (score 936):

You need to use the name attribute:

```
window.open("https://www.youraddress.com","_self")
```

**Edit**: Url should be prepended with protocol. Without it tries to open relative url. Tested in Chrome 59, Firefox 54 and IE 11.

Comment: The second argument is just a name to the new window, like the attribute `target=` of tag `a`. In fact, you can name your window whatever you like. All what you need is set it different value, so that it won't open in the same window or tab.

Comment: @ijse Actually, there are a few special names, one of which is '_self' which refers to the win/tab the code is running in. ;)

Comment: '_self' is not specified in the MDN [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open] docs on window.open(). A more cross-browser solution is to use location.replace().

Comment: The MDN link in the comment above is auto-linking to a 404. Link is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: `_self` is mentioned in section **5.1.6 Browsing context names** of the *HTML5 W3C Recommendation 28 October 2014* at: http://www.w3.org/TR/html/browsers.html#browsing-context-names (but `window.location` is still cleaner).

Comment: $window("www.address.com", "_self") - works also in angular way

Comment: Its not working, Well don't know the reason. I tried `window.location.href="....."`

Comment: @Qazi Yah. None of these solutions work for me either x). I actually WANT to open a file relative to the one i open from. Maybe firefox doesnt understand it? cleaning cashe or something needed? without the "_self" part it opens but in new window xP I did try "_blank" as per: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1165910 and now it works.

Comment: does it have to be "_self"? I tried it with other string names like 'testabcd' and it works

Answer (score 202):

Use this:

```
location.href = "http://example.com";
```

Comment: this is preferred to window.open (per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813879/window-open-target-self-v-window-location-href)

Comment: airbnb linter does not like location.herf. mentioning window at the beginning is the must.

Answer (score 110):

In order to ensure that the link is opened in the same tab, you should use `window.location.replace()`

See the example below:

```
window.location.replace("http://www.w3schools.com");
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.asp

Comment: It doesn't preserve the browsing history, we should not use it. instead try window.open("http://www.google.com","_top")  reference link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/open-a-link-without-clicking-on-it-using-javascript/

Comment: I am using this as part of an internal addon for internal pages and it's perfect. Browser history isn't really an issue as it's for automation and those using it have no business going to any of the pages manually. Thanks for the snippet!

Answer (score 48):

You can have it go to the same page without specifying the url:

```
window.open('?','_self');
```

Comment: That isn’t the same page. It will remove any query string from the existing URL.

Answer (score 22):

If you have your pages inside "frame" then 
    "Window.open('logout.aspx','_self')"

will be redirected inside same frame. So by using

```
"Window.open('logout.aspx','_top')"
```

we can load the page as new request.

Answer (score 12):

One of the most prominent javascript features is to fire onclick handlers on the fly. I found following mechanism more reliable than using `location.href=''` or `location.reload()` or `window.open`:

```
// this function can fire onclick handler for any DOM-Element
function fireClickEvent(element) {
    var evt = new window.MouseEvent('click', {
        view: window,
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true
    });

    element.dispatchEvent(evt);
}

// this function will setup a virtual anchor element
// and fire click handler to open new URL in the same room
// it works better than location.href=something or location.reload()
function openNewURLInTheSameWindow(targetURL) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = targetURL;
    fireClickEvent(a);
}
```

Above code is also helpful to open new tab/window and bypassing all pop-up blockers!!! E.g.

```
function openNewTabOrNewWindow(targetURL) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = targetURL;

    a.target = '_blank'; // now it will open new tab/window and bypass any popup blocker!

    fireClickEvent(a);
}
```

Comment: Or you can just do a.click();  instead of the whole fire click event.

Answer (score 12):

Open another url like a click in link

```
window.location.href = "http://example.com";
```

Answer (score 11):

Do you have to use `window.open`? What about using `window.location="http://example.com"`?

Answer (score 6):

`window.open(url, wndname, params)`, it has three arguments. if you don't want it open in the same window, just set a different wndname. such as :

```
window.open(url1, "name1", params); // this open one window or tab
window.open(url1, "name2", params); // though url is same, but it'll open in another window(tab).
```

Here is the details about `window.open()`, you can trust it!
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open

have a try ~~

Comment: The question is very clearly about wanting to open in the ***same window*** and ***same tab***!

Answer (score 5):

### open url in the current tab page using `_self`

```js
const autoOpenAlink = (url = ``) => {
  window.open(url, "open testing page in a same tab page");
}
```

```html
<a
 href="https://cdn.xgqfrms.xyz/index.html"
 target="_self"
 onclick="autoOpenAlink('https://cdn.xgqfrms.xyz/index.html')">
   open url in the current tab page using `_self`
</a>
```

### open url in a new tab page using `_blank`

```js
const autoOpenAlink = (url = ``) => {
  window.open(url, "open testing page in a new tab page");
}

// ❌  The error is caused by a `StackOverflow` limitation
// js:18 Blocked opening 'https://cdn.xgqfrms.xyz/index.html' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.
```

```html
<a
 href="https://cdn.xgqfrms.xyz/index.html"
 target="_blank"
 onclick="autoOpenAlink('https://cdn.xgqfrms.xyz/index.html')">
   open url in a new tab page using `_blank`
</a>
```

### refs

> According to MDN's docs, you just need to give one name of the new `window`/`tab`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Syntax

Comment: You can’t reliably know the name of the current window. Better to follow the advice from [this 2011 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8454535/19068) and use the special _self name.

Comment: Your first example is just wrong. _blank is, explicitly, an unnamed **new** window or tab.

Comment: not at all! if I set _self, it will open in current page which is bad for me, I just need one new page.

Comment: The question isn't about what **you** need! If you want to answer a question about what you need, then find a question asking for that.

Answer (score 2):

With html 5 you can use [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).

```
history.pushState({
  prevUrl: window.location.href

}, 'Next page', 'http://localhost/x/next_page');
history.go();
```

Then on the next page you can access state object like so

```
let url = history.state.prevUrl;
if (url) {
  console.log('user come from: '+ url)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Exactly like this
`window.open("www.youraddress.com","_self")`

Answer (score 1):

Thats pretty easy. Open first window as `window.open(url, <tabNmae>)`

Example: `window.open("abc.com",'myTab')`

and for next all window.open, use **same tab name** instead of `_self`, `_parent` etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Just Try in button.

   <button onclick="location.reload();location.href='url_name'" 
   id="myButton" class="btn request-callback" >Explore More</button>

   Using href 

  <a href="#" class="know_how" onclick="location.reload();location.href='url_name'">Know More</a>
```

Comment: It make no sense at all to trigger a reload of the current page and then cancel it in the next statement by loading a new page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
window.close();
window.open("index.html");
```

and it worked successfully on my website.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using APP SCRIPT then this is the solution:

```
<a id='someID' href='<?= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl(); ?>?requiredTab' hidden></a>

$("#someID")[0].click();
```