# Working example for top vs parent in html

Tags: html, html-target

Can someone give me working example of parent and top in html. I cannot find any example to know about this. Everywhere theoretical answers are available.

`_top`: opens in the outermost frame

`_parent`: opens in the parent frame

But i am not able to see any example.

Comment: Here is an example: http://output.jsbin.com/redilar

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_parent">Open in parent</a>`

`<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_top">Open in top</a>`

See [**a tag** description on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) and editable [example is here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_target).

EDIT:

The difference between `_top` and `_parent` is described in the accepted answer here [Difference between _self, _top, and _parent in the anchor tag target attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470097/):

> The _parent _top and framename tags are left a mystery to those that aren't familiar with the days of iframe site building as the trend.

Comment: where is parent in your answer?

Comment: In your example do you think there is some difference between top and parent??? both opens in self window.

Comment: See the difference between _top and _parent in the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470097/difference-between-self-top-and-parent-in-the-anchor-tag-target-attribute ... 
The `_parent` `_top` and `framename` tags are left a mystery to those that aren't familiar with the days of `iframe` site building as the trend.