# Write a jquery plugin to open a link in new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, window.open

I have wrote this plugin to open link to new window but does not work
any idea what might have gone wrong?

```
(function( $ ) {
     $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
        var defaults = {
            width: 800,
            height: 700,
            scrollbars: 1,
            location: 1,
            status: 1       
        },
        self = this,
        opts = $.extend(defaults, options);
        this.filter('a').click(function() {
            $("a").attr("target","_self");
            window.open($(this).attr('href'),'title', opts);
            return this;
        });
    };

}( jQuery )); 
$('a').myPlugin();
```

Comment: new window or new tab? @Евгений, I think he wants open link in a new window, so target="_blank"  can't do that.

Comment: I think you better read this one before done anything. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29969970/3967385

Comment: Just in new window. Yeah, I want to try plugin for the same. Its working if write a function for it, but does not work if I want to write it as plugin

Comment: numerous problems. Suggest you do some more research on basic plugin creation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead this

```
   opts = $.extend(defaults, options);
   this.filter('a').click(function() {
        $("a").attr("target","_self");
        window.open($(this).attr('href'),'title', opts);
        return this;
    });
```

try:

```
opts = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

$('a').click(function(){
   window.open($(this).attr('href'),'title', opts);
});
```

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) you can find examples of using `window.open()`. Also read [doc](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/):

> Keep in mind that the target object (first argument) will be modified,
>   and will also be returned from $.extend(). If, however, you want to
>   preserve both of the original objects, you can do so by passing an
>   empty object as the target:
>
> var object = $.extend({}, object1, object2);

Hope this help you.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing the options declatarion variable that you had in the extend function, the second paramater hasn't been defined.

```
(function( $ ) {
     $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
        var defaults = {
            width: 800,
            height: 700,
            scrollbars: 1,
            location: 1,
            status: 1       
        },
        options,   //<-------- This one right here !
        self = this,
        opts = $.extend(defaults, options);
        this.filter('a').click(function() {
            $("a").attr("target","_self");
            window.open($(this).attr('href'),'title', opts);
            return this;
        });
    };

}( jQuery )); 
$('a').myPlugin();
```

Good luck with the rest of the code.

Leo.

Comment: explain the differences and how it would help OP. Don't make people have to look for those differences

Comment: Sorry the explanation didn't get copied, I have updated the answer, cheers.

Comment: `options` is still undefined when used in `$.extend()`

Comment: Actually it is, that's the reason it is not showing your new window, try the code ;)

Comment: I'm not the OP ... am pointing out that `options` is undefined. This is not how to extend plugin options

Comment: Yeah well the thing is you have to set it before calling it in the $.extend(). Thats the actual error in console:
"Uncaught ReferenceError: options is not defined"

Comment: but it has to be passed in as function argument and  handled from there. Your solution does nothing to help OP use options. Also makes no sense modifying all `<a>` in page in click handler. Don't think you understand plugin basics either

Comment: Anyways, my solution works :) it could open a new window.