# Ajax call to jsp and jsp redirecting to further jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am having an ajax call to a jsp page which in turn is redirecting depending on the value of a flag variable being calculated in that jsp file.

ajax call is something like this :

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'uploadwebcamimage.jsp',
            type: "POST",

            data: {
                encodeimg: dataUrl,
                OwnerId: document.Clickpictures.OwnerId.value,
                OwnerPhone: document.Clickpictures.OwnerPhone.value,
                mobilepass: document.Clickpictures.mobilepass.value,
                emailpass: document.Clickpictures.emailpass.value,
                mypassword: document.Clickpictures.mypassword.value,
                mygroupuserid: document.Clickpictures.mygroupuserid.value

            },
            error : function(){ 
                alert('Error'); 
            },
            success: function(msg){
                //alert((msg));
                    if(msg.indexOf("true")>=0)
                    {
                        //how to get grouplist 
                        location.href="site_index_groupadmin.jsp?res1="+grouplist;  
                    }
                    else{
                        alert("UNSUCCESSFUL");
                    }
            }
        });
```

And in jsp i did something like this :

```
<%
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

     String query="Select GNAME from tbGroup";
     ps1 = con.prepareStatement(query);
     rs1=ps1.executeQuery();
     while(rs1.next()){
         list.add(rs1.getString("GNAME"));
      }
    //How can i send this list also to my ajax call.Please help

    if(flag==true){

    out.println(flag);

    }

    else if(flag==false){

    out.println(flag);


    }%>
```

But its not redirecting to other page.Please help

Comment: use jquery to get form field values or use `serialize()` and don't use `sendRedirect()` in other jsp, instead redirect in same page where you making ajax call.

Comment: @Rembo Though i solved the problem for redirecting.The problem Now is that i need to send an arraylist as an reuqest parameter.Please see my edited post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i send this list also to my ajax call.

use [Gson](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.2.4) or any other json library to write json response do like:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%
  //after generating your list

  Gson gson = new Gson();
  JsonObject root = new JsonObject();
  root.addProperty("flag", flag); //add flag
  root.addProperty("list", gson.toJson(list)); //add list

  out.println(gson.toJson(root));
  out.flush();
%>
```

and render list in ajax like:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'uploadwebcamimage.jsp',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json', //set dataType as json i.e. response data format 
        data: {
            encodeimg: dataUrl,
            OwnerId: document.Clickpictures.OwnerId.value,
            OwnerPhone: document.Clickpictures.OwnerPhone.value,
            mobilepass: document.Clickpictures.mobilepass.value,
            emailpass: document.Clickpictures.emailpass.value,
            mypassword: document.Clickpictures.mypassword.value,
            mygroupuserid: document.Clickpictures.mygroupuserid.value

        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
            alert(textStatus+' : '+ errorThrown);
        },
        success: function(response){
           alert(response.flag);
           $.each(response.list, function(key,value){
               alert(value);
           });
        }
    });
```

---

Edit:

As per your comment:

create a servlet instead of writing java code in jsp, and move java codes to servlets like:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    String query="Select GNAME from tbGroup";
    ps1 = con.prepareStatement(query);
    rs1=ps1.executeQuery();

    while(rs1.next()){
         list.add(rs1.getString("GNAME"));
    }

    //set flag
    boolean flag = true;

    Gson gson = new Gson();

   response.setContentType("application/json");
   response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");          
   PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();    

   out.write(gson.toJson(new ResponseResult(flag, list)));     
   out.flush();
}
```

and ResponseResult class looks like:

```
public class ResponseResult {

    private boolean flag;
    private List<String> list;

    public ResponseResult(){}

    public ResponseResult(boolean flag, List<String> list) {
        super();
        this.flag = flag;
        this.list = list;
    }

       //getters and setters
}
```

if you want to send list to any other jsp, then in servlet do like:

using request if you do forward:

```
   request.setAttribute("list", list);
   RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("pagename.jsp");
   dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

or alternate is using session if you do redirect then like:

```
//add list to session
request.getSession().setAttribute("list",list);
//get it back in another page like
List<String>myListObject=(List<String>) request.getSession().getAttribute("list");
```

Comment: I need to pass this list to this jsp page.How can i send it?Also how will i retrieve it on that site_index_groupadmin page?Also i need to do this if the flag is set to true.So do mention that also in your code.So i request you to please update your ajax call success part

Comment: @user3522121 if you want to send list to `site_index_groupadmin.jsp` then use `request.setAttribute("list", list);` then forward it. or better use servlets instead of jsp.

Comment: Also in this part : root.addProperty("list", list); its giving an error that no suitable method found for addProperty(java.lang.String,java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String)

Comment: And to retrieve it on other end.Will ArrayList<String> list1 = (ArrayList<String>)request.getAttribute("list"); work ?Where to write this : request.setAttribute("list", list);?Will i have to write it in ajax.

Comment: that error is now removed and problem is just on ajax call side

Comment: Please update your ajax part in solution.Am not getting it clearly

Comment: Also i checked for your code and it gives me error alert message in ajax call not success

Comment: @user3522121 i have given you a sample code how to do, you should make changes as per your requirement, check now answer updated

Comment: Its giving an error that parse error:Syntaxerror.JSONparsse : unexpected character

Comment: I resolved that error.It was silly mistake.But problem remains is that how to send this array obtained to required jsp?Also as this array is bit different how to get true array values from it

Comment: What about success part of ajax then,?Is it not needed?If flag is false then i need to stay on the same page .Where are you checking that?

Comment: Do you think forwarding here only what is the requirement.?I mean where should these lines be written RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("pagename.jsp");
   dispatcher.forward(request, response);

Comment: @user3522121 in servlet put these line in last of `doGet()` or `doPost()`.

Answer (score 1):

When you call a jsp via AJAX, you stay on the same page by definition, regardless of the headers sent by the server.

If you want to change the page, you must do it with javascript, in the success handler function for the `$.ajax(..)` call.

You can read the `Location` response header and set the `window.location.href` to that value. [See here for other options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454510/open-url-in-same-window-and-in-same-tab).

Get `PrintWriter` object by calling `HttpServletResponse`#`getWriter` and write your String.

```
response.getWriter().write("{isSuccess: true}");
```

now in jsp check isSuccess is true or false and use `window.location.href`

Comment: actually i was trying to do that also.What i was trying is to get that flag value in my ajax call and then make decision their.Can it be done ?

Comment: you just write you response back with some variable value and then you will able to determine

Comment: Please provide me piece of code to do the same.In actual i want is that if flag is true then redirect to other page otherwise stay on the same page (here same page is the page that is making the ajax call).

Comment: i did not get you.please provide code for ajax call also

Comment: Please see my edit in post.I resolved the problem of redirecting.But face anther problem.Please help