# How can I get my desktop push notifications in chrome to open in the same tab?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

It seems simple but I have been trying this for a while. Every time I add a link to the push notification, the urls open at different tabs for different links. Actually for the first notification, it opens in a single tab, for the second notification, it opens up in two tabs with the same url accessed. The tabs keep increasing.. please help.

```
for(i=0;i<newItems.length; i++){
        var myItem = {
            type: "basic",
            title: "New Product Alert!",
            message: newItems[i],
            contextMessage: "Product Notifier",
            buttons: [{
                title: "View Product"

            }],
            iconUrl: "origi.png"
        };

        chrome.notifications.onButtonClicked.addListener(function(){
            window.open('https://www.product.co.ke/electronics-video/');


        });

        chrome.notifications.create(myItem);



            }
        }
```

The newItems array is to fetch content for a new product uploaded

Answer (score 0):

You can try out adding "_self" as a second parameter in `window.open`. Similar to what [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454510/open-url-in-same-window-and-in-same-tab) suggested in doing.

Another route I can think of (mostly just looks like a more specific approach) is to call `chrome.tabs.getCurrent` inside the button click listener, and call the `window.open` function from there. Hopefully that will indicate Chrome that the currently viewed tab will open the url provided.

Hope this helps!