# What's wrong with my javascript code to open my url in same window with input value included?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

I want to open the url in the same window, my code below works fine if i open the url in another tab, but when i added the `_self` target to open it in the same window, it doesn't working :/
where is my error?

```html
<input type="text" name="url" id="url" value="brad.jpg" onclick="this.value=''" /><br/><br/>
<input type="submit"  onclick="javascript: window.open('http://MyURL.net/' + document.getElementById('url').value, '_self');">
```

Comment: try without self. By default, it should open in same tab.

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open URL in same window and in same tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454510/open-url-in-same-window-and-in-same-tab)

Comment: try double quotes instead of single `"_self"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracted the code into a function and it works fine:

```js
function callSubmit() {
  window.open('http://MyURL.net/' + document.getElementById('url').value, '_self');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="url" id="url" value="brad.jpg" onclick="this.value=''" /><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" onclick="callSubmit()">
```

Answer (score 0):

See this Fiddle : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2hckck96/2/)

```
<input type="text" name="url" id="url" value="brad.jpg" 

onclick="this.value=''" /><br/><br/>
<input type="submit"  onclick="window.open('http://www.google.co.in');" target='_blank'>
```