# javascript loading a file after a condition

Tags: javascript

When I use `window.open("file")` then it'll open the file as a new tab. I already tried `.load` but it doesn't work either. You may know how to solve my problem that the html file loads directly in the running window ?

```
function progress() {
   var prg = document.getElementById('progress');
   var percent = document.getElementById('percentCount');
   var counter = 5;
   var progress = 25;
   var id = setInterval(frame, 64);

   function frame() {
      if (counter == 100) {
          clearInterval(id);
          window.open("welcome.html")
      } 
      else {
          progress += 5;
          counter += 1;
          prg.style.width = progress + 'px';
          percent.innerHTML = counter + '%';
      }
   }
}

progress();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open URL in same window and in same tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454510/open-url-in-same-window-and-in-same-tab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the file in the current tab but adding the `_self` argument to the `name` parameter:

```
window.open("welcome.html","_self");
                              ▲
```

You can also achieve the same by using `window.location.href`:

```
window.location.href = "welcome.html";
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
window.location.href = "welcome.html";
```

It will open file in same tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.assign("welcome.html");` instead of `window.open("welcome.html");`

See this [article](http://www.corelangs.com/js/basics/redirect.html)