# How can I load a custom popup on a click event in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, highcharts

I have a highcharts bar chart and when I click on it I want to load a custom popup screen. This is my HTML page and I use [angular-data-table](https://github.com/swimlane/angular-data-table) for it.

```
<table datatable="ng" class="row-border hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Datasource</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody ng-controller="DashBoardcontroller">
    <tr ng-repeat="w in dashboard.Widgets">
        <td>{{w.Id}}</td>
        <td>{{w.description}}</td>
        <td>{{w.datasource}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

When I click on the bar chart I want [this template](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.bar.events.click) to show up.  I saw in the documentation of high charts this:

It shows a standard Alert popup. I use the chart from the documentation to test it:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            events: {
                click: function (event) {
                    alert(
                        this.name + ' clicked\n' +
                        'Alt: ' + event.altKey + '\n' +
                        'Control: ' + event.ctrlKey + '\n' +
                        'Meta: ' + event.metaKey + '\n' +
                        'Shift: ' + event.shiftKey
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

How can I load my HTML template as a popup?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.open("popupAddress?id=" + event.anyParameter);
```

Comment: Almost it's opening a new tab is there a way it can open on the same page?

Comment: I fixed it with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454510/open-url-in-same-window-and-in-same-tab