# how to navigate to the next page website on button click

Tags: html

[This is my login page called login.html and i want to open register.html page in the same tab when pressing register button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unv8H.png)

[This is the page(regeister.html) i want to navigate to when pressing register button in login.html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b6jd.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open URL in same window and in same tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454510/open-url-in-same-window-and-in-same-tab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this too

```
   <button>
    <a type="button" href="register.html"> register</a>
   </button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use  hyperlink to link once page to another

```
<a href="register.htm">Button</a>
```

if you using a `<form>` you can use form action  you can try this.

```
<form action="http://www.register.htm">
<button type=submit>Register</button>
</form>
```

or `onclick` method

```
<input type="button" name="b1" value="Register"
 onclick="location.href='register.htm'">
```