# Is there any way to let the user click a URL without opening a new tab?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular js app where I put an API link in the UI to which if the user clicks, he or she can enroll for a survey. Everything is fine but the problem is the user is also directed to the API link address that is a new tab opens. I basically want the user to just click it. So in the backend I know the user wants to enroll. But on clicking the link, the user also gets directed to a new tab.

This is my angular js code

```
<span ng-bind-html="message.link" ng-click="$event.preventDefault();"> </span>
```

Here it does stop it from going to a new tab but the link itself is not executed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you're "preventing the event" so the click will be canceled...

Comment: There must be more code going on than this but have you tried using the `_self` target attribute?

Comment: Possible duplicated :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454510/open-url-in-same-window-and-in-same-tab

Comment: @kawnah _self target attribute will let the link open on the same tab right?

Comment: " I basically want the user to just click it. So in the backend I know the user wants to enroll. But on clicking the link, the user also gets directed to a new tab." there's no (or very little) logic connection between these statements. Why do you think opening in a new tab changes anything about how the backend percieves the link being opened?

Comment: @SouvikRay I mean thats the default behavior of a link so that shouldn't need to be explicitly stated in the markup...but as the other user pointed out you're doing a `$event.preventDefault();` which makes me think there is more context that needs to be shared.

Comment: Use :`window.open(url, <tabNmae>)`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Actually I dont't want the user to be transferred to a new tab. You are right it has nothing to do with the backend..it is just that I want the user to stay in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you don't actually need a link.
The easiest way is to just remove the `a`. Instead, do a paragraph, or any other element and style it as a link.
In addition, just set an `ng-click` function, that will create the request you want to your back end, entirely invisible to the user.

Comment: Regardless of that, changing the syntax to ng-click and following the approach will do the trick