# How do I open an external url in flutter web in new tab or in same tab

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-web

I have a simple web app I have created with flutter web. I would like to know how I can open new an `external url` either in a `new tab` or in `the same tab` in my flutter web app. say I want to open the url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I think you want this — [`dart:js`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.3/dart-js/dart-js-library.html) enables interoperability between Dart and JS —:

```dart
import 'dart:js' as js;

// ...

FlatButton(
  child: Text('Button'),
  onPressed: () {
    js.context.callMethod('open', ['https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask']);
  },
)
```

Comment: lib/pages/home_page.dart:2:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:js'
import 'dart:js' as js;

Comment: @AyushGupta what version of flutter are you using to help you out? I tried this it works as of flutter v1.12.1 on channel master.

Comment: Even i am on master channel. But now i guess url_launcher_web is available, so might not needing this. But i haven't tried

Comment: Heres how to open in new tab or same tab
```js.context.callMethod('open', ['$url', isNewTab ? '_blank' : '_self']);```

source: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: @MaheshJamdade your url should start with https://

Comment: Thanks !
easy to use without install any third-party package

Answer (score 26):

One simple way is to just create a button and use `dart:html`'s [`window.open()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.4.0/dart-html/Window/open.html) method:

```dart
import 'dart:html' as html;

// ...

html.window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask', 'new tab');
```

The `name` parameter — which I left as `'new tab'` — refers to the new tab's window name, about which you can learn more from [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).

Comment: How to prevent this from failing if I have an Android version too?

Comment: It doesn't work with the mobile browser? I vaguely remember testing it on the emulator, but I'm not sure.

Comment: My flutter application has both the web and android target, but "import 'dart:html' as html;" will not work when building the Android version. So how could I prevent that part from being compiled for the Android target?

Comment: That's still strange, I thought `dart:html` would work an Android. My emulator is usually Android. At any rate, maybe you're gonna have to resort to [conditional imports](https://medium.com/@rody.davis.jr/how-to-build-a-native-cross-platform-project-with-flutter-372b9e4b504f)?

Comment: Yes, conditional import it is!

Comment: To prevent this from failing on mobile instead of html package you can use universal_html

Comment: universal_html's window.open doesn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 20):

As of `url_launcher: ^6.1.0` The plugin has support for `webOnlyWindowName` property, You can declare a wrapper function below

```
Future<void> launch(String url, {bool isNewTab = true}) async {
    await launchUrl(
      Uri.parse(url),
      webOnlyWindowName: isNewTab ? '_blank' : '_self',
    );
  }
```

and use it like this

```
onTap:(){
   launch('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask', isNewTab: true)
}
```

Answer (score 14):

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/url_launcher/url_launcher_web

`url_launcher` has been the solution for android and ios, recently it added support for web.

Comment: I am sorry, it does not say there how to use it. Could you please show me the code? I add import 'package:flutter/url_launcher.dart'; not even that works, there is no example

Comment: You can find documentation here https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

Comment: url_launcher can only open in new tabs/new window. The OP asked for "same tab" eventually.

Comment: Facing problem with Android 11

Comment: @MappaM `webOnlyWindowName:'_self',` do this.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the  [url_launcher plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher#-readme-tab-)

Then in your code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher_string.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: _launchURL,
        child: Text('Show Flutter homepage'),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

_launchURL() async {
  const url = 'https://flutter.io';
  if (await canLaunchUrlString(url)) {
    await launchUrlString(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

Example taken from the package site

Comment: I have tried and It does not seem to work for me on `flutter web`

Comment: The _launchURL() code works. All that's needed here is to follow the instructions at https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/url_launcher/url_launcher_web. Basically add the dependencies for **both** url_launcher and url_launcher_web in pubspec.yaml. Example:  `url_launcher: ^5.2.5
  url_launcher_web: ^0.1.0`

Answer (score 7):

Extending the answer of @xuyanjun which works fine when to want to open an external link from flutter web to a new tab. But if you want to open an external link to the website in the same tab in which the flutter web app is currently running.

then you can do it like this.

```
import 'dart:js' as js;
// ...

FlatButton(
  child: Text('Button'),
  onPressed: () {
    js.context.callMethod('open', ['https://blup.in/','_self']); //<= find explanation below
  },
)
```

Explanation :- dart:js package from flutter provide the functionality to call web-specific functions like `open` function from flutter and all the strings in the list are parameter which are passed to the function refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454510/open-url-in-same-window-and-in-same-tab).

So if you want to open new tab then not need to pass seconds parameter but if you wan to open in same tab then pass `_self` as second parameter.

Comment: This is the correct answer! The `marked as solved` answer does still open in a new tab and is therefore not a complete answer to the authors question.

Answer (score 5):

Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56656885/361832

Flutter Web does not support plugins (yet), so you have to use replacements from `dart:html`

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-html/Window/open.html window.open(url, 'tab');

or

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-html/Window/location.html  window.location.assign(url);

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to launch the URL in the same tab.

```
window.top.location.href = '<your url>'
```

Must import

```
import 'dart:html';
```

Answer (score 0):

package url_launcher now has web support.

just import url_launcher_web, and url_launcher to your pubspec.yaml

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
const String _url = 'https://flutter.dev';

void _launchURL()   {
   launch(_url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To launch **URL** you need to import [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) with latest version and you are good to launch URL through following code:

```
//Launch Github

_launchGithub() async {
const url = 'https://github.com/Pranav2918'; //Paste your URL string here
if (await canLaunchUrlString(url)) {
   await launchUrlString(url);
 } else {
   throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

- For non string URLs:

Another approach :

```
final Uri _url = Uri.parse('https://flutter.dev');
 Future<void> _launchUrl() async {
  if (!await launchUrl(_url)) {
   throw 'Could not launch $_url';
  }
}
```

**Happy Fluttering !!**