# How do I link http url to flutter-web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, openurl

I'm learning flutter web.
I'm trying to open another url when button is clicked.
Is there any way like this:
`onclick: ()=>openurl("https://test.com")`
How can I achieve this?
Please help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

UPDATE: This is a VERY old "issue" from Flutter Web and has already been resolved using the "[**url_launcher**](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)" package

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
const String _url = 'https://flutter.dev';

void main() => runApp(
      const MaterialApp(
        home: Material(
          child: Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: _launchURL,
              child: Text('Show Flutter homepage'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

void _launchURL() async {
  if (!await launch(_url)) throw 'Could not launch $_url';
}
```

Current easiest way to do it is by using **`href`** with your **`html`** library:

```
import 'dart:html' as html;

html.window.location.href = "https://www.google.com" // or any website your want
```

Put that code inside your `onTap` method and that's it.

Comment: how to navigate to another page with post parameters, "html.window.location.href" only works with get parameters

Answer (score 3):

You can now use `url_launcher` just like for other platforms, web support has been added.

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/url_launcher/url_launcher_web

Comment: how open in same tab?

Comment: got it `webOnlyWindowName:'_self',`

Answer (score 2):

Flutter Web does not support plugins (yet), so you have to use replacements from `dart:html`

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-html/Window/open.html
`window.open(url, 'tab');`

or

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-html/Window/location.html     `window.location.assign(url);`

Answer (score -3):

There is a plugin to achieve this: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher

Import the plugin;

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

openURL() async {
  const url = 'https://test.com';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

Call the method

Comment: I am not being able to import dart plugins. I get this error:  Because webapp depends on url_launcher >=3.0.0 which requires the Flutter SDK, version solving failed.

Flutter users should run `flutter packages get` instead of `pub get`.

Comment: please find more details about this, https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

Comment: I am not being able to import native flutter plugins in flutter web.

Comment: flutter web does not support plugins right now. Any plugins.