# Open external link with Flutter Web 1.9

Tags: flutter-web

I have a Flutter web project, started with flutter_web and migrated to 1.9, all works great but no way to make a external link work.

There're some solutions in stack overflow but any of the solutions don't seems to works as expected, tried all from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56220691/how-do-i-open-an-external-url-in-flutter-web-in-new-tab-or-in-same-tab)  and similar other ones, I supouse the accepted questions would work before 1.9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `flutter 1.10`, we can use [universal_html](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html) package to open external link:

```dart
import 'package:universal_html/prefer_universal/html.dart' as html;
// ...
html.window.location.assign('https://stackoverflow.com');
```

Answer (score 1):

As of today, you can use `url_launcher` to open urls for flutter web app. It supports both relative and absolute urls.
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/url_launcher/url_launcher_web

Answer (score 0):

Now you can alternatively add `url_launcher_web` [dependency](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher_web) along with `url_launcher` and then use `launch` and `canLaunch` functions from `url_launcher` package for your web project as if it was mobile.

```
# pubspec
  url_launcher: 5.2.7            # the newest version rather than ^5.1.4
  url_launcher_web: ^0.1.0
```

Seems like it's a temporary solution though, to be merged with the main `url_launcher` plugin. For now it only works on web but ruins the mobile build (Flutter v1.12.16-pre.35).