# How to combine Flutter Web and Angular site

Tags: angular, flutter, web

I have an angular site with some functionality (WebRTC), and need to add this site as-is to Flutter Web application, enable navigation between them.

How to do that?

Comment: Both builds create index.html. Configure your web hosting server to understand which routes go to which index file. Instead of using the platform routing, just do typical `window.location` routing as needed.

Comment: I want to click a button in flutter web and redirect to another index.html

Comment: See this answer for redirecting to external URLs in Flutter => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56220691/how-do-i-open-an-external-url-in-flutter-web-in-new-tab-or-in-same-tab