# Is there anyway to open a page in new tab in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, web

I've created a web app with flutter and I want to open the second screen in a new tab. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Please research before asking. Here is one existing answer => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56220691/how-do-i-open-an-external-url-in-flutter-web-in-new-tab-or-in-same-tab

Comment: @daddygames I'm not trying to open an external link. I want to open a page in my own app in a new tab.

Answer (score 2):

```
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html;

 static openNewTab({String setUrl, String setTitle}) {
    return html.window.open(
      setUrl,
      setTitle,
    );
  }
```

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Comment: universal_html is lib used in flutter web. Code is very easy as window.open() is for opening new tab which receives url and title. Url is of your page or can be any.

Comment: This will not work in iframe

Answer (score 0):

In your current tab view, build the URL for the new page, then launch it using one of these methods:

[How do I open an external url in flutter web in new tab or in same tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56220691/how-do-i-open-an-external-url-in-flutter-web-in-new-tab-or-in-same-tab)

Then, configure your app for for reading query parameters. You can then use those parameters to determine the starting view for your app in the new browser tab.

Here is a discussion about ways to handle query parameters:

[How can a named route have URL parameters in flutter web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57552885/how-can-a-named-route-have-url-parameters-in-flutter-web)

Alternatively, [uni_links](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links) is a package that I have used for deep linking. You can also use this as a way to control what view your user sees at a specific link. The package allows your app to listen for URLs, then you can inspect the parts of the URL and take an action based on parameters, such as navigating to a specific view.