# Open a different URL in the same window

Tags: javascript

I have a question regarding `window.open()`. I need to open a new URL in same window, while passing some data from the previous window (different URL) .

I have code which is passing data to other window but it is opening new window.

Any suggestion how to open it in same along with data?

```
window.open(url,PREFIX + JSON.stringify({"some":"somevalue"));
```

Comment: You can check this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454510/open-url-in-same-window-and-in-same-tab

Comment: but its not passing any data , i want data+self

Comment: Data can be passed as query string. check my answer. `_self` is target.

Comment: What do you mean by _"same window"_? Do you mean the current browser window or a window created by a previous call to `window.open()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass _self in your method

```
window.open(url,PREFIX + JSON.stringify({"some":"somevalue"), "_self");
```

Comment: thanks it works , i did some silly mistake i guess.

Comment: its not working :( it is opening the new window.

Answer (score 0):

Use `location` object for directing the same window to open another url.

```
window.location.replace(url + PREFIX + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({"some":"somevalue"})));
```

OR

```
window.location.href = url + PREFIX + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({"some":"somevalue"})};
```

---

If you don't want to expose the data in the url, you have to send a reference to the data and the target website should find data via the reference.

Comment: i do not want to expose the data in url.

Comment: how to send reference ?

Comment: It is just a number or alphanumeric value which you pass in the url. URI encoded data is the only way you can transfer data to a website when you are initiating it for the first time.