# Redirect class onclick with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need some Javascript help as I'm not very good at it. I'm trying to redirect a breadcrumb link when clicked:

`<a href="/tiles" class="ProductItem-nav-breadcrumb-link">Tiles</a>`

I've tried this;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementsByClassName(ProductItem-nav-breadcrumb-link).onclick = function () {
        location.href = "newURL";
    };
</script>
```

and this;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.querySelector('.ProductItem-nav-breadcrumb-link').onclick = function () {
        location.href = "newURL";
    };
</script>
```

Neither of these worked. Does someone have a better solution?

Thanks

Comment: It's explained really well here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454510/open-url-in-same-window-and-in-same-tab

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
window.location.href = 'https://example.com/';
```

or

```
 document.location.href = 'https://example.com/';
```

Booth examples should work.