# Open link / in class with javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello i want to code an scirpt that downloads / opens an link thats in an class as an href (you can see it on the picture i sent)

i dont know how to do it because im not an experienced coder

i already tried this to pieces of code but without success

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("mycode_color")[0].click(`href`);

document.getElementByClassName('exito_thx message').src = url;
```

i want that the scirpt opens this href in an new tab

[image]

does someone know if its possible and how its done?

or does someone know is its possible to code it to open every link that has "attachement.php" in it?

**edit**: it's much complicated than i thought it would be

[image]

every link is in his own name & id

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open URL in same window and in same tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454510/open-url-in-same-window-and-in-same-tab)

Comment: What is "*an like in an class*"?

Comment: Check the post i edited the post

Comment: The `<a>` element has no `class` attribute. So your script can't find the element to get the link.

Comment: Does this mean its not possible or is there a way around?

Comment: Try `document.querySelector('.exito_thx.message a')`

Answer (score 0):

The `a` element given in the image doesn't include a class name. Hence you can't target it with a class name. Try this...

```
window.open(document.querySelector('a').href);
```

It opens the first encountered `anchor` element in the webpage.

Comment: The first one worked but i think its getting much conplicated i only realised not that every "post" has his own id and class (https://imgur.com/a/9TJlrjE)