# how can url be hidden in hyperlink when mouse hover

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, hover

How can I hide URL from displaying when mouse hovers on a hyperlink?

```
<a href="url">Hyperlink</a>
```

How can I hide URL from displaying in browser's bottom status bar when mouse hovers?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to do something sketchy. As far as I know there is no way to prevent this behaviour, to prevent people from trying to cover up where the link may lead. Duh.

Comment: many times you may have seen that no url is displaying when mouse hovers on that hyperlink, how is it? for security resons?

Comment: Its done with th method described by Simeon. I for one don't trust sites that use that method; it's not nice, I like to know where I'm going and it's unnecessary obfuscation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't put the URL in the `href` (or keep it `href="#"`) and attach a JavaScript function to the `onclick` event which puts the actual link in the `a` element. This way you won't see the actual URL when hovering over the link but the link will be inserted when the user actually clicks.

Comment: ok but i can see that # here, nothing should be displayed e.g hover on Add Comment in this stackoverflow site, no url is shown on that hyperlink how?

Comment: There is no `href` attribute in that element here on Stack Overflow, you could try that. So when clicking, the JavaScript function should add the `href` attribute with the URL as value.

Comment: can you please show a demo like that? with an example so that i can test here

Comment: Well, to be fair, you asked a question as to how it was done. I'm sure you can write the JavaScript function easily as it's only one or two lines at most.

Comment: i am new to javascript and here i am trying but no result. I hope you can write better to show a demo

Comment: The JavaScript function should call: `document.getElementById('id_of_the_link').setAttribute('href', 'http://www.google.com');` where `id_of_the_link` and the URL should be modified of course.

Comment: @SimeonVisser Can you please edit your post with full JavaScript code and html code.

Comment: This doesn't work! What I see is `https://originURL/#`. Latest Edge browser.

Comment: You can also do `javascript: void(); return false;` if you're in asp.net land, and put the "real link" in an `onclick()` event, as mentioned.  
In my case I have a long gnarly javascript function that is called that doesn't look good on the screen.

Answer (score 8):

**This way you can easily hide url when mouse hover on hyperlink.**

Simply add one id on anchor link.

**HTML**

```
<a href="url" id='no-link'>Hyperlink</a>
```

**Jquery code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      setTimeout(function () {

            $('a[href]#no-link').each(function () {
                var href = this.href;

                $(this).removeAttr('href').css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function () {
                    if (href.toLowerCase().indexOf("#") >= 0) {

                    } else {
                        window.open(href, '_blank');
                    }
                });
            });

      }, 500);
});
```

Here is demo link https://jsfiddle.net/vipul09so/Lcryjga5/

Comment: Do you mind explaining why the `setTimeout` is needed?

Comment: Try without setTimeout. You realize what happen there.

Comment: It is working fine without `setTimeout` and @vipulsorathiya no offence but my mind is melting because of your `if` condition. :D

Comment: @vipulsorathiya hahaha!! hmmm, well if good developers getting `indexOf` special characters after converting value `toLowerCase` and leave their if conditions blank then I'm good as a very poor developer. :D

Comment: @RajnishCoder There are some special code but its not visible for you. :(

Comment: @vipulsorathiya I need help, I use this code but I don't want to open in new window.

Comment: @YvetteLee - You could use `window.open(href, '_self')`. I have used it and there have been no problem so far. _Find this intuitive_. Tested with both FF and Chrome. However there is [another school of thought](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4813887/13823230).

Answer (score 5):

you technically have [`window.status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.status) to make custom status bar messages. you can set it during an "onmouseover" event for that element and set the `window.status` to a blank string.. thats how we did it a *long time ago* however..

browsers these days prevent the modification of the status bar by default (as far as i know, firefox prevents it). so there is no guarantees as to this approach will do anything at all.

Answer (score 3):

```html
<button class="class" onclick="window.location.href='https://stackoverflow.com'">Visit StackOverflow</button>
```

OR

```html
<button class="class" onclick="window.location.replace('https://stackoverflow.com')">Visit StackOverflow</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use onclick="location.href='#'"

Answer (score 0):

just remove **href** attribute from **a** element. :)