# How to hide the URL when hover over a link?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Would it be possible for when I hover over the image the href won't display the link to the raw video? (bottom left of web browser)?

Also, how can I disable right click so they won't get the video options.

```html
<article>
  <a class="thumbnail" href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4">
    <img src="http://i.livescience.com/images/i/000/026/853/iFF/ocean-waves-beach.jpg?1336055104" alt="" />
  </a>
</article>
```

Since no video tags are being used, I'm not to sure about this.

My idea was maybe the href would toggle a javascript function. The function would pretty much do the same thing. store the raw link in a variable.

Comment: Look for http://stackoverflow.com/a/9851396/1980659

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With CSS only, you can set up a layer on top of the link. Below is an example of using pseudo element `:before` + some `position` tricks.

```css
article {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
article:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <a class="thumbnail" href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4">
    <img src="http://i.livescience.com/images/i/000/026/853/iFF/ocean-waves-beach.jpg?1336055104" alt="" />
  </a>
</article>
```

With JavaScript, try the following approach.

```html
<article>
  <a class="thumbnail" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:location.href='http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4'">
    <img src="http://i.livescience.com/images/i/000/026/853/iFF/ocean-waves-beach.jpg?1336055104" alt="" />
  </a>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable rightclick by adding `oncontextmenu="return false"` to your video.

```html
<video controls="" autoplay="" name="media" oncontextmenu="return false"><source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4" oncontextmenu="return false"></video>
```

Comment: That disables it on the image. Not the video once it is in display. I need the right click disabled for the video.

Comment: Then simply add it to the video, which works as well ;) - added a new snippet. You can just as well add it to the entire body. This will prevent people from right-clicking anywhere and opening the inspect-menu. However, it'll always be possible to view the source code of your site.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. I obtained the solution.

href set it to hash:

```
href="#"
```

Add an onclick attribute that runs a JS function:

```
Onclick="video()"
```

For the function add this:

```
Function video() {
   window.location.href ='VIDEO LINK HERE';
}
```

To disable the videos right click menu. All i did was add this to the body tag:

```
oncontextmenu="return false;"
```

Luckily for me, I can disable the whole pages right click. Since i have no video tag i can't use it on the video tag.