# Hide URL of mouse overing link

Tags: javascript, html

**UPDATE**

---

I finally found a simple and easy way:

```
<font onclick="window.open('https://www.google.pt/', '_self');" style="background:0;border:0;outline:0">Link
```

I had to use a tag to add the event to the text so I used `font` because it doesn't modify anything.      P.S.: This doesn't work on JS Fiddle as, for some reason, it doesn't open the link (it stays blank).

---

Probably duplicated but I couldn't find it so, is there any way to prevent the URL of a link to show when I move my mouse over it?
Code with image of the URL:

```
<a href="https://www.google.pt/">Google</a>
<br>
When I over the mouse on the link, it shows the URL on the bottom left corner.
<br>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/pq3ket7.png">
<br>
Is there any way to prevent it?
I'm using Chrome.
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1tbg478j/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can url be hidden in hyperlink when mouse hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851372/how-can-url-be-hidden-in-hyperlink-when-mouse-hover)

Comment: Theres no way to do this reliable in every browser. Aswell there should **NEVER** be the need to do that - why do you wanna do that? - You can use javascript if you don't want to show where the link goes. => `onMouseOver="window.status = ''"`

Comment: @PatrickEvans I think the solution is on the 1st answer of that link. It's not exactly but it's a trick, a way around it.

Comment: @Xatenev You say it should NEVER be done, however, even here on the site, the "Add Comment" button does that (doesn't show any URL but works like a link).

Comment: @TheUsualClient, maybe in Firefox, but in Chrome if you hover over "add comment" you get `...-overing-link#` in the status bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSFiddle broke so I will just paste all the code here. Please note that the links won't work in JSFiddle because they do not allow window.location but it will work in your website.

HTML:

```
<a class="no-href" data-location="https://www.google.pt">Google</a><br />
<a class="no-href" data-location="https://www.google.com">Link 2</a><br />
<a class="no-href" data-location="https://www.google.co.za">Link 3</a><br />
<a href="https://www.google.pt/">Normal Link</a><br />
<br>
When I over the mouse on the link, it shows the URL on the bottom left corner.
<br>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/pq3ket7.png">
<br>
Is there any way to prevent it?
I'm using Chrome.
```

JS:

```
$('.no-href').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = $(this).attr('data-location');
});
```

CSS:

```
.no-href {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: A little bit trick but it works. Thanks! ...and to the others saying it's impossible, just don't...

Comment: The Jquery will work for all the links, so if you have other links on the page you might want to only select a certain class, not all of them, otherwise your other links won't work. Other than that you should be golden.

Comment: @Chris Does it have to open the link in another tab?

Comment: It is useful if you are building an app.

Comment: No it can work like a normal link. I will add another link in my answer, give me a minute.

Comment: @Chris If you provide the code of 2 working links without the URL and the new tab, I can do the rest (on my code).

Comment: @TheUsualClient It is because your script is loading before the elements exist. Your code should be inside this: $(function(){ // Code Here });

Comment: @Chris So, instead of writting my HTML code I do it all in JavaScript? I'm a little confusing, can you help me get it working please.

Comment: @Chris I found a way, I'm gonna update my original question.

Answer (score 0):

It's uncontrolled browser behavior.
You can convert it to a div, attach a click event listener an open the wanted url in the callback function.

Comment: Sorry, I don't like limitations.

Comment: Of not being able to control that with a simple attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add it to OnClick like this:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="location.href='https://www.google.pt/'">Google</a>
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score -1):

According to this it cant be done : https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/chrome/discuss-chrome/FtD7qjochgw