# How to hide url shown at bottom of browser when hover on link?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using colorbox with iframe true option for links to open.

In fancybox, I used a code to hide url shown at bottom of browser when hovered on link button.

**But I am stucked at how to do it for colorbox.**

I want solution for this following code :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".iframecolor").colorbox({
       iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"
   });
});
</script>
```

And `<a>` tag used is as follows :

```
<a class="iframecolor btn btn-success" href="http://www.linkofwebsite.com">VIEW NOW</a>
```

Here I want **to hide** showing http://www.linkofwebsite.com shown at bottom of browser when we hover on *`VIEW NOW`* button.

==========================================================

==========================================================

The working code for **fancybox** used earlier is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.fancybox').fancybox();          

        $("#fancybox-manual-b").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open({
                href : 'test.html',
                type : 'iframe',
                padding : 5
            });
        });

        $(".fancy").fancybox(); // ***This worked for fancybox to hide url  
    });
</script>
```

AND in `<a>` tag, code used as follows :

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe more_info_btn" data-fancybox-href="http://www.linkofwebsite.com">VIEW NOW</a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851372/how-can-url-be-hidden-in-hyperlink-when-mouse-hover

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can url be hidden in hyperlink when mouse hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851372/how-can-url-be-hidden-in-hyperlink-when-mouse-hover)

Answer (score 0):

According to the colorbox documentation it can accept a href parameter, like you did with fancybox

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".iframecolor").colorbox({
        iframe:true, 
        width:"80%", 
        height:"80%",
        href:"http://linkofwebsite.com"
    });
 });
</script>
<a class="iframecolor btn btn-success" href="#">VIEW NOW</a>
```

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/